# Why is this simple PUT request timing out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

```
def convert_vend_types_param
    if params[:schedule_machine][:vend_types].present?
      vend_types = []
      params[:schedule_machine][:vend_types].each_pair do |vt, active|
        vend_types << vt.to_sym if active.to_i > 0
      end
      params[:schedule_machine][:vend_types] = vend_types
    end
  end

api :PUT, "/v1/schedules/:schedule_id/schedule_machines/:id", "Update a schedule machine"
  param_group :schedule_machine
  error :code => 422
  def update
    convert_vend_types_param

    if params[:schedule_machine]
      if params[:schedule_machine][:products_returned_at]
        new_date = params[:schedule_machine][:products_returned_at]
        if @schedule_machine.products_returned_at == nil || new_date.to_date > @schedule_machine.products_returned_at.to_date
          ScheduleMachineProductCounterJob.new.async.perform(@schedule_machine.id)
        end
      end
    end

    unless @schedule_machine.update_attributes(params[:schedule_machine])
      render(json: { error: 'Invalid schedule machine information' }, status: :unprocessable_entity) and return
    end

    render :show
  end
```

My request and timeout:

```
2015-01-13T17:52:06.437358+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"token"=>"mytoken", "schedule_machine"=>{"remove_verified_at"=>"2015-01-13"}, "schedule_id"=>"58", "schedule_location_id"=>"2178", "id"=>"4874"}
2015-01-13T17:52:06.437292+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Api::V1::ScheduleMachinesController#update as JSON
2015-01-13T17:52:07.441605+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered api/v1/schedule_machines/show.json.rabl (740.3ms)
2015-01-13T17:52:10.681136+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=PUT path="/api/v1/schedules/58/schedule_locations/2178/schedule_machines/4874.json" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=1e4ea64a-8552-4e5d-8580-3c2a8d04ec49 fwd="107.77.72.114" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has a hard limit of 30s for a request. Your request was killed at (service=30001ms) so one of the steps in the method is the problem.

It looks like either you could have a database timeout (maybe because of a deadlock which would be weird, or something else blocking) or your async job is not returning as quickly as you thought it would.

If you're using NewRelic or Skylight you can look deeper into the request to see what
s going on. You could also run the commands from a console.

Comment: In this case, the async job shouldn't be hit -- I'm just updating a model attribute

Comment: Are there any callbacks on the model that might be triggering (and timing out?)